# Sync my Dropbox, Onedrive or OneNote with my personal FTP server?

Tags: windows-7, file-synchronization, ftp, dropbox, microsoft-onenote

I'm looking for a way to sync my Dropbox, Onedrive and OneNote one way to my personal FTP server.

- Dropbox ==> FTP
- OneDrive ==> FTP
- OneNote ==> FTP

It would be neat to have it both ways, but the one way is the most important for now.

Is there a software like this around? I'm not talking about the standard clients of each software, I'd like to have 1 software where I can add dropbox/onedrive/onenote and possibly other file hosters, which in turn allows me to sync at least one way to my FTP.

I know of [FTPBox](http://ftpbox.org/), but that's not what I'm looking for.

Software should run on Windows 7, paid solutions are fine.

Comment: It seems that the OneNote syncing protocol is not documented, unfortunately :-/ Typical of Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for DropBox, try run Dropbox from scheduler as described in [DropBox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202122759-sync-when-not-logged-in), it sync files locally. And then sync FTPBox or other way to desired location.

**UPD:**

[rclone](https://rclone.org/) can be used to sync dropbox and many other cloud storages from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudsfer to migrate the data from Dropbox and OneDrive to your personal FTP server with the option to perform a sync to ensure that your personal FTP is up to date.

Please check out Cloudsfer for more info,

Thanks,
Roy - The Cloudsfer Team.
http://www.cloudsfer.com/

Answer (score 0):

MultCloud can be a rather considerable option, I’ve used this app for several months and it seems like working pretty well so far. I somehow read an article on the MultCloud official website about how to migrate files between clouds and I immediately fell in love with this product. All I need is to transfer my files easily and fast and MultCloud meets my demand perfectly, so I would literally share it with everyone. I just searched on the MultCloud page and got this tutorial for you, you can have a try. [Dropbox to FTP Transfer](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/dropbox-to-ftp-transfer-3889.html)

Comment: Hi Gabrielle1024.  All of your answers so far recommend this single product.  Please disclose any affiliation you have with this product.  Thanks, the Software Recommendations StackExchange moderation team.